# Postgres: copy database from one server to another on AWS RDS using PGAdmin

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have 2 postgres database instances on my aws account, basically they both run different engines of postgres and there is no way to downgrade. so I resorted to creating an instance with the engine version that I require and then perform a database copy of all the objects/data. I am trying to use the following command but is throwing an error.

```
pg_dump -h sourceinstancexx.awsxxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com -U myUser-W myPass-d myDB | psql -h destinationinstancexx.awsxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com -d desinationDB -U DestinationUser -W DestinationPW
```

The error is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_dump"
LINE 1: pg_dump -h xx.xx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.c...
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run pg_dump as if it was an SQL command. You should use the backup tool provided in PGAdmin, or get access to the system shell and run the pg_dump command from there.